# MassTransit UseCluster causes application to fail

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

We have a cluster setup for RabbitMQ and we are using MassTransit for managing message types, configuration etc. When we turn off a node in the cluster we get exceptions like the below, directly on running the application, meaning the whole application is down.

```
{
    "Depth": 0,
    "ClassName": "RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException",
    "Message": "None of the specified endpoints were reachable",
    "Source": "RabbitMQ.Client",
    "StackTraceString": "   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)\n   at MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.ConnectionContextFactory.CreateConnection(ISupervisor supervisor)",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "HResult": -2146232800,
    "HelpURL": null
},
```

The problem disappears when the node is back up. But with a high availability setup we want the application to just choose another node when some of the nodes is unavailable.
I suspect it is the way we setup MassTransit, which is with the following:

```
x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
   {
      cfg.Host("cluster", rmq.VHost, h =>
      {
         h.Username(rmq.Username);
         h.Password(rmq.Password);
         h.UseCluster(c =>
         {
             foreach (var node in rmq.Nodes)
             {
                 c.Node(node);
             }
         });
     });
     cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});
```

Anyone who have faced this issue before and know if there are any configurations in masstransit we can use for the application to "try the next node if one is unavailable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was not related to MassTransit, but due to the way the cluster was configured. I work in an enterprise setup where a high availablity cluster will not have a mirror policy as default. Read more here:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html#what-is-mirroring

Answer (score 0):

It should report the error, but continue down the list to connect to an available broker node in the cluster. If you don't see the error repeated every few seconds, it found an available node and connected.

If you look at the full log (not just ERROR level), you should see the connection attempts to the various nodes.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response Chris. We looked into the logs as suggested, and figured out it was a mirror-configuration issue with our RabbitMQ cluster.